# Uniq based on last field, keeping last line, and append number of duplicates

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, columns

I need some help to implement awk command in a bash script for implementing below logic. Tried sort/uniq combination, but no luck.

I have a long list with time stamp and some number in front of it like below.

```
[2020-09-15 09:03:21.835335] 1021
[2020-09-15 09:03:21.935335] 1021
[2020-09-15 09:03:22.835335] 1022
[2020-09-15 09:03:25.835335] 1022
[2020-09-15 09:04:21.835335] 1023
[2020-09-15 09:05:21.835335] 1023
[2020-09-15 09:04:22.835335] 1023
[2020-09-15 09:05:23.835335] 1023
```

In the final outcome, I want to process the list with respect to column 2 above with numbers. In the final processed data, I wanted to have count of unique numbers (even if the occurrence is just once) from column 2 and add it in a new column in front of number. What I really needed was to have time stamp from last occurrence of duplicate/unique entries from number column.

```
[2020-09-15 09:03:21.935335] 1021 2
[2020-09-15 09:03:25.835335] 1022 2
[2020-09-15 09:05:23.835335] 1023 4
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! To put things in code blocks as I did, use indentation. For more, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tac file | uniq -c -f 2 | awk '{$(NF+1)=$1;$1=""}1' | tac
```

`tac` prints the file from in reversed order. This is to guarantee that the last occurrence of the duplicated lines will be kept.

`uniq -c -f 2` only compares the last field by skipping the first two with `-f 2`. It prepends the number of duplicated lines with the `-c` flag, so we have to transfer the count number to the last field. That is what `awk '{$(NF+1)=$1;$1=""}1'` does.

Finally, `tac` puts all back in order.

```
 [2020-09-15 09:03:21.935335] 1021 2
 [2020-09-15 09:03:25.835335] 1022 2
 [2020-09-15 09:05:23.835335] 1023 4
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '{map[$3]=$1" "$2; cnt[$3]++} END{for (key in map) print map[key], key, cnt[key]}' file
[2020-09-15 09:03:21.935335] 1021 2
[2020-09-15 09:03:25.835335] 1022 2
[2020-09-15 09:05:23.835335] 1023 4
```

The above will output the lines in random order, if they need to retain input order it's a small tweak.